# Are hats being released early

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2013

I have just got the "[Ho Ho Ho](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/237/mark#winter-bash)" Hat.Isn't that a bit early as I am in GMT and the time is 1310.

Or do we get then whenever it is Dec 25 anywhere?

Comment: you should enjoy this and don't think about it.

Answer (score 8):

No, the SO server just gives the hat to anyone within 12 hours of Christmas UTC time.

It's always Christmas in Iceland!